# Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'mobilePhone' of resource 'User'. in Azure AD access via graph query

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to access users on base of certain property (mobile phone) from azure AD but getting above mentioned error
I have even try to add ConcistencyLevel header and count = true query parameter but not success
My code s as following

```
try
            {
                ClientSecretCredential authProvider = new ClientSecretCredential("*******", "********", "*********");
                List<Option> options = new List<Option>
                {
                    //new QueryOption("count", "true"),
                    //new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel","eventual")
                };
                var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
                var user = await graphClient.Users.Request(options).Filter("mobilePhone eq '1111222223333'").GetAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Please let me know what i am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I were able to filter by adding $ in count paramter

My working code is

```
try
            {
                ClientSecretCredential authProvider = new ClientSecretCredential("*******", "********", "*********");
                List<Option> options = new List<Option>
                {
                    new QueryOption("$count", "true"),
                    new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel","eventual")
                };
                var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
                var user = await graphClient.Users.Request(options).Filter("mobilePhone eq '1111222223333'").GetAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```